# How do I compare whether two web pages have the same layout and content?

Tags: apache, https, automation, comparison, frontend

The two URLs

```
http://www.bbprescott.com/
```

and

```
https://www.bbprescott.com/
```

have the same content although one starts with "http://" and the other starts with "https://". Instead of checking them manually, how can I compare them automatically, a script that returns true if they have the same content, and false if they don't.

Comment: do you want to verify that the two web pages are stritly the same ? Where do you want to send the boolean value from comparison ?

Comment: @Nico Yes, I just want to verify whether the two pages are strictly the same. It doesn’t matter where I send the Boolean for comparison. I just want to write a script to compare them. It doesn’t matter how I do it. Any idea? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I based my answer on this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/234810/how-do-i-compare-two-files-with-a-shell-script)

You can adapt it for your needs

Create a file called for instance myscript.sh with this content :

```
#!/bin/sh
wget --output-document=url_http.html http://www.bbprescott.com/
wget --output-document=url_https.html https://www.bbprescott.com/

diff --brief url_http.html url_https.html >/dev/null
comp_value=$?

if [ $comp_value -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "The two web pages are different"
else
    echo "The two web pages are identical"
fi

rm -f url_http*.html
```

Then on command line add execution right to your logged in user :

```
chmod u+x myscript.sh
```

Then execute it :

```
./myscript.sh
```

An if you want to see the differences between your two url content, you can execute manually :

```
wget --output-document=url_http.html http://www.bbprescott.com/
wget --output-document=url_https.html https://www.bbprescott.com/
diff url_http.html url_https.html
```